# ECMAScript 5.1 internal method [[Call]]

Tags: ecmascript-5

I need help in understanding that algorithm:

> [[Call]]
>
> When the [[Call]] internal method for a Function object F is called with a this value and a list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let funcCtx be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of F's [[FormalParameters]] internal property, the passed arguments List args, and the this value as described in 10.4.3.
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]] internal property. If F does not have a [[Code]] internal property or if its value is an empty FunctionBody, then result is (normal, undefined, empty).
> 3. Exit the execution context funcCtx, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If result.type is throw then throw result.value.
> 5. If result.type is return then return result.value.
> 6. Otherwise result.type must be normal. Return undefined.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1

Exactly I need in explanation in 2,4,5,6 clauses.

About 2: First, what does the result of the FunctionBody calculation mean? How is it calculated? What does it mean there is no [[Code]] property when this happens? And most importantly, what does this record mean (normal, undefined, empty).

About 4,5,6: What does result.type mean, result.value? Where does this value come from? Explain for each point

P.S If you vote down, explain why you do that!

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You are asking several different, independent questions.

Comment: @RobertColumbia 
And what should I do? Cut it into a few dozen questions. Which most likely nobody will answer? I do not ask you to paint in great detail, I ask you to explain these nuances. I understand much easier to ask about how to print hello world in a browser and get hundreds of answers to this than to ask about things that few people are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the [[Call]] is propabily about `Function.prototype.call()`, so it's better to understand `call()` first because it's easier than algorithm.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

I get this sample code from the MDN, and try to answer the question roughly. (If you want to understand in detail, you and I have to understand the whole specification, but I don't!)

```
function greet() {
  var reply = [this.person, 'Is An Awesome', this.role].join(' ');
  console.log(reply);
}

var obj = {
  person: 'Douglas Crockford', role: 'Javascript Developer'
};

greet.call(obj);  // Douglas Crockford Is An Awesome Javascript Developer
```

### About 2

> First, what does the result of the FunctionBody calculation mean?

FunctionBody is function's code. From the sample, FunctionBody is below.

```
var reply = [this.person, 'Is An Awesome', this.role].join(' ');
console.log(reply);
```

`the result of the FunctionBody calculation` is the result of the code execution. The result is expressed by **Completion Specification Type**(explain below). It includes the function `return` value, but has more  wider information.

> What does it mean there is no [[Code]] property when this happens?

It's mean empty function as below.

```
function greet() {
    // empty
}
```

> And most importantly, what does this record mean (normal, undefined, empty).

It's [Completion Specification Type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.9). This is an expression for value or statement in specification.
Values of the Completion type are triples of the form *(type, value, target)*.

### About 4,5,6

> What does result.type mean, result.value? Where does this value come from? Explain for each point

result is Completion Specification Type, and the form is *(type, value, target)*.

Comment: I like your answer. And your explanation about `Completion Specification Type` - excellent. Thx for help!